# How to embed markdown generated by a service in Polymer?

Tags: markdown, polymer

Embedding the markdown directly works; embedding markdown generated by a service does not.

- I suspect this may be a messaging issue; to do the equivalent in Angular I needed an observer on the html element

  I've modified the mark-down.html to set reflection on

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/kp69YpPEHDCQU4h1sOUN)

```
    <div class="container" layout vertical center>
      <div layout vertical>

        <content-service markdownItems="{{localMarkdown}}"></content-service>

        <mark-down markdownText="{{localMarkdown.md}}"></mark-down>

      </div>
    </div>
```

- To bypass the Plunker CORS error, open browser with google-chrome --disable-web-security on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial to setup with core-ajax and [marked-element](https://github.com/Polymer/marked-element)

```
<core-ajax auto url="http://jsbin.com/xagutu/1/quiet"
           response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
<marked-element text="{{response}}"></marked-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sefeta/1/edit

**Note**, the demo currently produces a JS error but has been fixed in https://github.com/Polymer/marked-element/commit/3bd94abab31d5253a67a4e46063b7afb5cf3db17.

Comment: Works beautifully Eric; thanks.  Plunker updated for posterity.